# Most Python-ic way to collate a group of CSVs based on a common key?

Tags: python, csv

**The Problem**: I have a group of CSV files, imagine they're named a.csv, b.csv, etc.  They all share a common structure of first name, last name, phone, email, and the common key is `source` - where I got the data from.  I collated all of those CSV files into one massive CSV.

Now, it can be the case that 1 individual can be in all of the CSV files - i.e., imagine if the source was a website - the same individual's profile is listed on each website, so each source is different, but the rest of the data is the same.  This would mean I end up with data like:

```
John,Doe,867-5309,johndoe@fake.com,Website A
John,Doe,867-5309,johndoe@fake.com,Website B
```

I have the CSVs collated into one massive CSV, but I'm having trouble how to best complete the latter portion - sorting by the common key.  Ideally, I'd want it so that the source is a list instead of a string - a list of all the sources.  So, instead of the code sample above, I want to make the data look like this:

```
John,Doe,867-5309,johndoe@fake.com,Website A,Website B
```

**Attempted solutions**: Not my first rodeo here, so I know I have to show my work.  My initial idea was to iterate through all of the agents in the collated CSV file, save their emails to a list, then iterate again through all of the list of agents and the list of emails - if the agent's email and the iterated email are the same, then I add the source from the iterated email to the agent's `source` column, and continue on as necessary.  Here's the code I used to achieve that:

```
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, source, first_name, last_name, phone, email):
        self.sources = []
        self.source = source
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email

    def writer(self):
        with open('final_agent_list.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            row = [self.first_name, self.last_name, self.phone,
                 self.email]
            row.extend(i for i in self.sources)
            csv_writer.writerow(
                row
            )
agents = []
with open('collated_files.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in tqdm(list(csv_reader)):
        a = Agent(*row)
        for agent in agents:
            if agent.email == a.email:
                a.sources.append(agent.source)
            else:
                a.sources.append(a.source)
                agents.append(a)
    for agent in agents:
        agent.writer()
```

For a minimum, complete verifiable example, use the following as `collated_files.csv` :

```
John,Doe,867-5309,johndoe@fake.com,Website A
John,Doe,867-5309,johndoe@fake.com,Website B
```

However, when I run that, I *do* get a list of sources as hoped.. but they aren't collated.  When I run that, a good example of the output would be:

```
John,Doe,867-5309,johndoe@fake.com,[Website A]
John,Doe,867-5309,johndoe@fake.com,[Website B]
```

Clearly, it's not combining the two as I want, but I can't figure out what's making the code go wonky.  Do any of you wonderful folks have any ideas?  Thanks for reading!

Comment: I fixed the indentation of your code, but please double check, as it is a matter of interpretation.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you break out of the loop as soon as you find one match, and so your agent will always end up with one value in `sources`. [You fixed this in a later edit].

Secondly, the inner `else` will also kick in, even if in a previous iteration there was an email match, and so you still get to append duplicate agents. And as there are more agents, the more iterations the loop will go through, and the more duplicates you add.

I would suggest using a dict, as it will allow faster lookup of a matching email:

```
agents = {} # create a dict keyed by email
with open('collated_files.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in tqdm(list(csv_reader)):
        a = Agent(*row)
        # if this is a new email, add it to the agents
        if not a.email in agents: 
            agents[a.email] = a
        # in all cases add the source
        agents[a.email].sources.append(a.source)
    for agent in agents:
        agent.writer()
```

Comment: The break was from old code that I meant to ex-out, sorry about that - but the rest of your idea is sound.  I'll give this and the other answer a try later tonight.

Answer (score 1):

To be more pythonic (and to make that work), what I would do:

- use `collections.DefaultDict` to associate a list with the key, which is a `tuple` made of all values but the last one (the website)
- read the input csv files in a loop and create the dictionary
- write a new csv file and recreate the rows using concatenation of the key and the values (the gathered websites)

like this:

```
import collections,csv

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for input_file in ["in1.csv","in2.csv"]:
    with open(input_file) as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            d[tuple(row[:-1])].append(row[-1])

with open("out.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows((k+tuple(v)) for k,v in d.items())
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'll give this and the other answer a try later tonight, and award the answer accordingly.